# ImageView Blur by setAlpha method

Tags: android, android-imageview

I want to show the image of an ImageView in the "Blur" property,

So for doing this I apply the imageview.setAlpha(int)

Here it takes 0 to 1 as 0 for transparent, and 1 for opaque

so how i do this i want to pass floating value to Blur my image, is there any other way to doing this.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Is there any one please give me some solution

Comment: `Blur` diffs from `Alpha` value, `Alpha` is for transparency.

Answer (score -2):

it takes a hexadecimal float  .

so iv.setAlpha(0x00) is for transparent and iv.setAlpha(0xff) for opaque .

is it what you want ?